# Share buttons for EmberJS app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to add social share buttons (fb, twitter, vk) to my Ember app. I found some libraries and integrated them, but they have an important restriction. Social networks crawl shared page with their bots and retrieves specific meta properties from the page. But these bots doesn't execute JS so they don't see dynamically generated properties.

So what solution could be implemented in this case?

Comment: You need Ember [FastBoot](https://www.ember-fastboot.com/).

Comment: It has significant drawback (for me): it requires node.js server and doesn't work with jquery. So I can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there was no addon that not relies on meta properties. So after some research I have created my own addon. It gives me a possibility to share links with title, description, image etc **without meta tags and server rendering**. Addon just used url-parameters provided by social networks. Now it works great for vk and fb, and partially works for twitter.

Maybe it helps someone besides me - [ember-social-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-social-share).